# Filter rows based on a swapped combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

Imagine I have a data frame with three columns were column 1 and 2 depicts unique combination with a certain output *'value'*. However, I want to filter out those rows were the columns are actually just swapped, since the outcome is the same and retain one outcome of one set of combination.

e.g. 
2 - 1 = 1
and
1 - 2 = 1 
is technically the same

```
df <- data.frame(column1 = c(2,3,4,1,3,4,1,2,4), 
                 column2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 value = c(1,2,10,1,2,4,2,2,5))
```

Since I don't have any reasonable code which can tackle this issue, I appreciate any help and hint!!

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the given dataframe?

Comment: out <- data.frame(column1 = c(2,3,4,3,4,4), column2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), value = c(1,2,10,2,4,5)

Comment: in fact there are > 10k pairs within the data frame where column1 and column2 are swapped where indeed the output is the same (derived from hamming distance calculation). Since, 1 : 2 == 2 : 1 I want to filter out all those duplicated events with the same output! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pmin` and `pmax` to sort the columns and then select unique rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(temp1 = pmax(column1, column2), 
         temp2 = pmin(column1, column2)) %>%
  select(temp1, temp2, value) %>%
  distinct()

#  temp1 temp2 value
#1     2     1     1
#2     3     1     2
#3     4     1    10
#4     3     2     2
#5     4     2     4
#6     4     3     5
```

Comment: This is amazing!! Thank you so much :)